# TermColor doesn't print in color

Tags: python, windows, colors, terminal, termcolor

I've been trying to print text in color in the Python Terminal with the TermColor Module (I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.7), here's my code:

```
from termcolor import colored

while True:
    print (colored("Hi my name is red text", "red"))
```

But it returns me this:

[image]

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Does anything *else* print in colour through the same terminal? It may not support it.

Comment: Yeah, the CMD works... But anyway thanks Davis, it worked :D

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is not a duplicate.  The conhost supports VTY in Win10.  If the OP isn't on Win10, then yeah, duplicate.  Otherwise, using `termcolor` solo should be working.

Comment: In action: `print("\x1B[31mHello!\x1B[0m")`.  `1B` is hex for `27` which is the charcode for `ESC`.